# Set representations of double quantifications

Tags: elementary-set-theory, quantifiers

This might be a silly question, but somehow I cannot get my head around it. Suppose there are two sets of sets, $X_p$ for all $p \in P$, and $X_q$ for all $q \in Q$. If it holds that:
$$ \forall p \in P, \exists q \in Q : X_p \subseteq X_q,$$

then
$$\bigcup_{p \in P} X_p \subseteq \bigcup_{q \in Q} X_q.$$

But I cannot understand why this holds. Moreover, are these two representations equivalent?

Comment: If every man lives in a house, the collection of all men lives in the collection of all houses.

Comment: More formally, consider a specific $X_p$; then you can find some $X_q$ such that $X_p \subseteq X_q \subseteq \bigcup X_q$.

Comment: But if $X_p$ is a set whatever of the collection, then the fact above holds for every $p \in P$ and thus all the $X_p$'s are subsets of $\bigcup X_q$. And thus, also their union will be.

Comment: It can be  helpful to consider examples. Consider P(N) and P(Z), powerset of naturals and integers. Hopefully, it is intuitive that if you are a subset of naturals, you are also a subset of the integers. Therefore, of we take the union of all the subsets of natural numbers, then we have a subset of the union of all subsets of integers.

Comment: Imagine $P$ is the set of musicians in the Berlin Philharmonic Orchestra, $Q$ is the set of musicians in the Chicago Symphony Orchestra, and for any musician $m$, $X_m$ is the set books in $m$’s personal library.  Then what would the problem’s condition mean and what would its conclusion be saying?